# Why won't my TableRowFilter filter?

Tags: swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I'm trying to filter a JTable using a TableRowFilter . It works for me on a simple example , but I can't seem to get it to work on the real thing. The filter is called , the logs are printed - but I staill see the rows . Any ideas?

```
public class TopicTable extends JTable {

...

public TopicTable(ITopic topic) {

    super();
    TopicTableDataModel model = new TopicTableDataModel(topic);
    setModel(model);
    setRowSorter(generateTableRowSorter(model));        
    setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    setColumnRenderers();       
}

private TableRowSorter<TableModel> generateTableRowSorter(TableModel model) {

    RowFilter<Object, Object> classFilter = new RowFilter<Object, Object>() {

        @Override
        public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends Object, ? extends Object> entry) {
            log.debug("Filtering? " + entry.getValue(1));
            return false;
        }

    };

    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    sorter.setRowFilter(classFilter);
    return sorter;
}

...
}
```

Comment: What is different between your simple example and complex example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all stupid bugs go - this was one of them . In another class that use this table , I used table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true) - so even thought the original sorter still ran , the default one also did , and then nothing happened.